# Can not find any package of tile for TCL/Tk in fedora 19

Tags: tcl, fedora, rpm, tk-toolkit

I am porting a tcl/tk application to tcl8.6 from ActiveState Tcl8.5. I have successfully done that for Ubuntu14 and windows. But I have been unable to find any package for tile in Fedora 19 - 64 bit repository. I do not want to install the tile package by compiling it from source. Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Fedora 19 is EOL. You should update to current version to get security updates.

Comment: Yeah, true. 
Actually fedora 19 is the minimum requirement for our application. Thats why I have to make it compatible in fedora 19 also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're doing something really obscure (like using an uncommon theme), you shouldn't need that package. All its main features — including *all* its widgets — are incorporated into Tk 8.5 (and 8.6) as the `ttk` widget set.

Comment: Yeah. Exactly!
Just a minute ago I realized that. 
after doing "package require Tk"; "package require tile" is doing just fine.